# Как скомпилировать файл asm и выполнить его на Linux?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, компиляция

Я создал файл `asm` файл и скомпилировал его с помощью команды

```
 nasm file -o outfile
```

Как теперь выполнить программу в терминале? (Запустить outfile)?

Comment: Для тренировок с ассемблером в linux я бы использовал обычный gcc. Пишете файл с расширением .s (в [синтаксисе AT&T](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81), проще всего взглянуть на него откомпилировав сишный код `gcc -S prog.c`) и получаете исполняемый модуль вызовом `gcc -o myprog myasm-src.s`

Answer (score 3):

По умолчанию `nasm` (обычно) компилирует в `bin`-формат, что равносильно обычному плоскому коду. Вообще говоря, такие файлы не являются исполняемыми практически ни для какой ОС. Но если файл сформирован специальным образом, в начале `asm`-файла пропущен блок в 256 байт т.е. в начало добавлено:

```
org     0x100
```

То этот файл будет эквивалентен `COM`-формату DOS. Его можно запустить в эмуляторе DOS'а, например `dosbox`.

---

Чтобы скомпилировать исполняемый файл для linux нужно явно указать формат:

```
nasm file -f elf64 -o file.o # создаст объектный файл (указать elf32 для x86)
ld -s file.o -o outfile      # слинкует объектный файл в исполняемый
```

Но для этого код должен быть написан непосредственно для linux (использовать его системные вызовы и т.п.).

Запускать его можно как обычно:

```
./outfile
```

---

Список доступных форматов можно посмотреть с помощью `nasm -hf`

Comment: Терминал выдает Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, значит программа неправильно написана...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091559/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-nasm-ubuntu-%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0 Вот вопрос с кодом

Answer (score 0):

Как и все программы в Linux:

```
./outfile
```

или

```
<path_to_file>/outfile
```